# How to add user in firebase database that does not already exists?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

```
    export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  users: any;
  constructor(private fs: FirebaseService, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth ) {


  // console.log(  this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.email);
      // this.fs.addUsers();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fs.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
          if (this.users[0].email === this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.email ) {
            console.log("this user already exists");
          }
          else if (this.users[0].email !== this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.email) {
             this.fs.addUsers();

          }
          console.log(this.users[0].email === this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.email);
          console.log(this.users[0].email);
          console.log(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.email);
    });

  }

}
```

This is my code; I want that when log in the user is added to a list of users (stored in firebase database); however I want to check whether the user already exists in the list. therefore I wrote this function. However it is called repeatedly and does not stop. My question is: How do I change the function so it does not go in an infinity loop?

ps I work with angularfire 4.0.0 / angular 4.1.3 /firebase 4.0.0

edit:

```
  getUsers() {
this.users = this.afd.list('/users') as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>
return this.users;
```

}

Comment: Show this function `this.fs.getUsers()`

Comment: I think you can add another layer of filtering new data through firebase cloud functions

Comment: @theblindprophet see edit thanks in advance